# VB.Net Nested If

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, logic

I have some logic and a certain if condition is not being reached. I have tried several variations of if/ifelse/else to create the logic I want, but nothing correctly works. Let me show you in some code...

```
If(a is true) Then
print("A is true")

Else If(b is true) Then
print("B is true")

    if(c is true) Then
    print("B and C are true")

    else 'c is Not true
    print("B is true, C is Not true)

        if(d is true) Then
        print("B and D are true")

        else 'd is Not true
        print("B is true, D is Not true")

        End If
   End If
End If
```

What is happening is that my

"If(d is true)" and "else 'd is not true"

conditions are not checked. That part of the logic is being "stepped over"

Expected output when A,B,C, and D are true:

"A is true"

Expected output when B, C, and D are true:

"B is true"

"B and C are True"

"B, C, and D are True"

Expected output when B and C are true but D is not:

"B is true"

"B and C are True"

"B is true, D is not true"

Expected outcome when B and D is true:

"B is true"

"B is True, C is not true"

"B, and D are true"

What I am currently seeing:

B,C and D are true:

"B is true"

"B and C are true"

Which leaves out "B and D are true"

Hopefully these outcomes help you understand!

Comment: Follow your logic. C will only ever be checked if B is true. Likewise, D will only ever get checked if B is true and C is not true. What kind of output are you looking for, exactly? I think, in this case, it might be better to check each of A, B, C, and D separately, and concatenate a string together.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have gone ahead and edited to include my desired/expected outcome. I like you suggestion, but I only want to test for C and D if B is true first. And if A is true, I don't care about anything else. Sorry the original was confusing. Hopefully this makes sense now.

Comment: The fact that some of these statements are being repeated is fine. In the end I use some logic which places the final expression written and puts it in a table and ignores earlier expressions.

Comment: Remove the brackets. `If()` is a method for checking and returning objects in one line. The correct way for you is: `If a Is True Then` and for ElseIf: `ElseIf b Is True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what a,b,c or d are but here is what I think you are trying to do. You just need to change the string only if"d" is either true or false based on your "use case". If you want more granularity, then I would suggest a string builder as mentioned before. At any rate, here is the code i used to create your "case" To be clear "c" and "d" are never checked if "b" is false. I based this of what your "use case" stated.

```
 Private Sub Test()
            Dim a = True
            Dim b = False
            Dim c = True
            Dim d = True

            Dim printout As String = ""
            If a Then
                printout = "a is true"
            Else
                If b Then
                    If c Then
                        printout = "b and c are true"
                    else
                      printout="b is true and c is not true"

                    End If
                    If d and c Then
                        printout = "b and c and d are true"

                    elseif d=true and c=false then

                        printout = "b and d are true , c is not true"
                    elseif c=true and  d=false then
                     printout = "b and c is true ,d is not true"  
                    else
                     printout = "b is true ,c and d are not true"              


                    End If
                End If
            End If
            Console.WriteLine(printout)

        End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that a,b,c and d are all boolean functions that return true or false provided a parameter of "x". I made that very confusing, I'm sorry. Your code looks good, but I do need the print statement ""B is true, C is Not true". In other words, I really need to have an else statement after "If c Then"

Comment: Made edits, again this is not optimal but accomplishes what you asked